# Set deployment order in Wildfly 10

Tags: deployment, wildfly-10, sar

I have 1 ear and some sar to deploy, I need to deploy sar1 before sar2, I tried to include jboss-all.xml inside Meta-INF in my sar2, but without results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">  
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">  
        <dependency name="sar1.sar" />  
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>  
</jboss>
```

How can I set the deployment order?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it but the RedHat EAP docs indicate that there are several possibilities listed here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18317

From the article:

**Filename based ordering**

**Default order of deployment**

- deployer
- -deployer.xml
- sar
- -service.xml
- rar
- -ds.xml
- har
- jar
- war
- wsr
- ear
- zip
- bsh
- last

The DeploymentSorter can be changed by changing the configuration in $JBOSS_HOME/server/$PROFILE/conf/jboss-service.xml

Assuming it works for WildFly also, you might just try renaming them to get the depoyment sorter to pick them up for filename based ordering?

Comment: But that is according to JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (EAP) 4.x wildfly can't even has $JBOSS_HOME/server/$PROFILE/conf/jboss-service.xml

Comment: You are correct it is documentation for quite an old version. however unless you have already tried it, i would still start there for the default DeploymentSorter, lacking any other docs to this matter. The page was updated fairly recently after all.